# How to add datatips in a fitted surface chart

Tags: matlab, plot, datatip

I have created a fitted surface from x, y, z data points. How do I insert `data tips` for the min and max value in the chart?

```
defDM_fit = fit([def_X, def_Y],def_Z,'cubicinterp');
clf;
figure(2)
plot(defDM_fit,[def_X, def_Y],def_Z);
```

using the following test code is raising an error "*Invalid argument. The object has been deleted or does not support data tips*":

```
datatip(defDM_fit, def_X(1), def_Y(1), def_Z(1))
```

And I do not know how to manage that tips show up at min and max value in the chart by code.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the datatips to the `plot` and not to the `fitobject` object? (i.e. `p = plot(defDM_fit,[def_X, def_Y],def_Z); datatip(p, def_X(1), def_Y(1), def_Z(1)) `). I cannot check because your example is not [Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @BillBokeey, thanks. I did and it will lead to the same error.

Comment: Can you add data to make the example reproducible, so that I can try? I am pretty sure it is just a matter of object types

Comment: @BillBokeey, give me a second...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotting a fitted surface created with `fit` outputs a 2x1 graphics array. The first element is the surface (Surface object), the second element is a Line object that holds the points on which your data was fitted. In order to add datatips, you will have to use one of these two objects, and more probably the Surface object, for example:

```
load franke
T = table(x,y,z);

f = fit([T.x, T.y],T.z,'linearinterp');
p = plot( f, [T.x, T.y], T.z );

datatip(p(1),T.x(1),T.y(1),T.z(1))
```

[image]

Comment: cool it works with `p2 = plot(defDM_fit,[def_X, def_Y],def_Z);` and `datatip(p2(1),def_X(1), def_Y(1), def_Z(1))`
I try to find the indexes for the min and max def_Z values. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `datatip` is a graphic object, not a surface/line fit object.

```
defDM_fit = fit([def_X, def_Y],def_Z,'cubicinterp');
figure(2)
p=plot(defDM_fit,[def_X, def_Y],def_Z);
datatip(p, def_X(1), def_Y(1), def_Z(1))
```

There are many other things that may be wrong with your approach, particularly because you are showing a surface plot (`surf`) in your example, yet your code uses a line plot (`plot`). I am not even sure what the arguments even are, the way you are putting them.

Consider reading the documentation of the functions you are using, as they come with examples on how to use them: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html

Comment: I did use exactly the documentation from your link. I use the `fit` function to generate the fitted surface as in the docs. Maybe the code line `datatip(defDM_fit, def_X(1), def_Y(1), def_Z(1))` is wrong. I do not know how to use it right to create data tips within my chart.

Comment: but thanks for the hint to the graphic object.

Comment: By the way the `plot` function I use is from the Curve Fitting Toolbox and plots `cfit` and `sfit` objects. So, `plot` is not only for line plots. See [HERE](https://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2022a/curvefit/cfit.plot.html?s_tid=doc_ta).